# How are you supposed to install a Python library using azure webapp as template?

Tags: python, visual-studio, azure, flask, kudu

I have access to the Azure Portal.

From there, i have setup a free so called "webapp" using the FlaskAzure(python) template. (https://github.com/azureappserviceoss/FlaskAzure)

I have installed MS Visual Studio 2015(with "python tools"), and MS Visual Studio 2017RC(which doesn't have python support just yet).

I want to install a library called "docx".

My question is: **How am i supposed to install new libraies?**
It might be possible to install it in several ways, as i also have access to kudu with terminal access.
I just wonder if i actually have to use the terminal, or if i can use the MS VS2015 with python tools to do this, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
So the fix was actually to create a new webapp from scratch without flask and python. It has to be a regular webapp.

Then to add python as an extension.

As far as i have understood, this is because there is some changes going on with the python/flask webapps, and there will be a fix for this later on.

After i installed as described the link, it seems to work: https://prmadi.com/running-flask-app-with-httpplatformhandler-in-azure-app-services/

It was a bit hard to understand it all from the tutorial, but if you have problems create a support ticket within the azure portal, as they will guide you through the guide.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a `requirements.txt` in the root of the project, when the build is going to be deployed, kudu will detect that file, scan it and try installing those packages automatically during deployment.

you can create `requirements.txt` with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Take a look at this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/06/29/install-native-python-modules-on-azure-web-apps-api-apps/

Comment: There is already a requirements.txt file. It originally contained only: "Flask<1". Can i just put in a new line and add "docx" without any version number, as i just need the latest one? And how do i trigger so that the kudu will check the requirements file and install libs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have now tried to create a whl file on my local computer. The result was two .whl files. I added them in the requirements file and uploaded the files using kudo. This is how the setup looks like now: http://oi64.tinypic.com/155pix2.jpg . Still doesn't work. I also tried to add them manually in kudo console, but got this error message: http://pastebin.com/8XknArph . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @patchie Please check the version of `six` module whether be too low without the function `wraps` for `six`. If so, please upgrade it. On my environment, the `six` module version is `1.10.0` for `docx` package.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT: I'm not sure how to check for the module version, and didnt seem to find something called six in the libs folders on the azure server. So i tried to run a command i found online "pip freeze", and it just gave me the same error message. So i installed six using "easy_install-2.7.exe six". So now i have a file here, but still the same error message when trying to use pip: "Installed d:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg"

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT: I added some more information about what i have tested and error messages on this forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/313d4b2e-78bb-45e0-9805-063185b48685